# Calling native C++ sensor functions in Windows Phone from C#

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone-8

I have some problems when calling Windows::Devices::Sensors::Accelerometer::GetDefault() in C++ through a Windows Runtime Component (as a wrapper) on my Windows Phone application from C# code.

I followed this guide on the subject: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Windows_Phone_Native_C%2B%2B_and_DirectX_-_First_Direct3D_App,_setting_up_Touch_and_Sensors#Accelerometer

In my Windows runtime component constructor, I just initialize the accelerometer:

```
WindowsRuntimeComponent::WindowsRuntimeComponent() {
    accelerometer = Windows::Devices::Sensors::Accelerometer::GetDefault();
}
```

but when I make a reference to the Windows Runtime Component project in my Windows Phone C# project, and I call the constructor like this:

```
WindowsRuntimeComponent winrtcomp = new WindowsRuntimeComponent();
```

When I start the emulator, it gives the exception "WinRT information: The specified procedure could not be found.". If I remove the GetDefault call, then the exception goes away. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was as simple as upgrading the .NET target version to 4.0.